# What happens if two functions have the same derivative on an interval?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $ f $ and $ g $ are differentiable functions on the interval $ [a, b] $ such that $ f^\prime (x) = g^\prime (x) $ for all $ x \in [a, b]$.

How can I prove that " f = g modulates a constant ", that is, that there is a constant $ k $ such that $ f (x) = f (x) + k $ for all $ x \in [a, b] $. Considering the function $ f - g $ and applying the mean value theorem.

I appreciate the help you can give me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `proof-writing`?

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Incase you want it without using the mean value theorem:

let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$

Differentiating both sides, $h^\prime(x) = f^\prime(x) - g^\prime(x)$

Since $f^\prime(x) = g^\prime(x)$, we can say $h^\prime(x) = 0$

Therefore, $h(x) = \int h^\prime(x)dx = $ a constant ($k$).

So $f(x) - g(x) = k$ and $f(x) = g(x) + k$